# Why do i get "table already exists"?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, migration

I'm trying to migrate to my database but i get a:

> The table with name 'compteur_honore.ingredientsrecettes' already exists.

I checked my Entities and i don't see any mistakes, there must be one but i can't find...

```php
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ingredientsRecettes", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="recette_id", columns={"recettes_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="ingredients_id", columns={"ingredients_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\IngredientsrecettesRepository")
 */
class Ingredientsrecettes
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Recettes
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Recettes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="recettes_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $recettes_id;

    /**
     * @var \Ingredients
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ingredients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ingredients_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $ingredients_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantite", type="float", nullable=false)
     */
    private $quantite;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getQuantite()
    {
        return $this->quantite;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $quantite
     */
    public function setQuantite($quantite): void
    {
        $this->quantite = $quantite;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId(int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Recettes
     */
    public function getRecette_id(): ?Recettes
    {
        return $this->recettes_id;
    }


    public function setRecettes_id(?Recettes $recettes_id): self
    {
        $this->recettes_id = $recettes_id;
    }

    public function getIngredients(): ?Ingredients
    {
        return $this->ingredients_id;
    }


    public function setIngredient(?Ingredients $ingredient): self
    {
        $this->ingredient = $ingredient;
    }
}
```

```php
class Recettes
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Ingredients::class)
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ingredientsRecettes")
     * joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ingredients_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     * inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="recettes_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *
     */
    protected $ingredients;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ingredients = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="text", length=65535, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNom(): string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $nom
     */
    public function setNom(string $nom): void
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId(int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getIngredients()
    {
        return $this->ingredients;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $ingredients
     */
    public function setIngredients($ingredients): void
    {
        $this->ingredients = $ingredients;
    }

    public function addIngredient(Ingredients $ingredient): self
    {
        if (!$this->ingredients->contains($ingredient)) {
            $this->ingredients[] = $ingredient;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeIngredient(Ingredients $ingredient): self
    {
        if ($this->ingredients->contains($ingredient)) {
            $this->ingredients->removeElement($ingredient);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

```php
/**
 * Ingredients
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ingredients", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="unite_mesure", columns={"unitesMesure"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Ingredients
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="text", length=65535, nullable=false)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var \Unitesmesure
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Unitesmesure")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="unitesMesure", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $unitesmesure;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId(int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNom(): string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $nom
     */
    public function setNom(string $nom): void
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;
    }

    public function getUnitesmesure(): ?Unitesmesure
    {
        return $this->unitesmesure;
    }

    public function setUnitesmesure(?Unitesmesure $unitesmesure): self
    {
        $this->unitesmesure = $unitesmesure;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

When I use the command `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` I get the message:

> The table with name 'compteur_honore.ingredientsrecettes' already exists.

Here is the migration

```php
final class Version20190805125202 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function getDescription() : string
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE boulangerie DROP FOREIGN KEY boulangerie_ibfk_2');
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE recettes_ingredients (recettes_id INT NOT NULL, ingredients_id INT NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_33E6DB8E3E2ED6D6 (recettes_id), INDEX IDX_33E6DB8E3EC4DCE (ingredients_id), PRIMARY KEY(recettes_id, ingredients_id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE recettes_ingredients ADD CONSTRAINT FK_33E6DB8E3E2ED6D6 FOREIGN KEY (recettes_id) REFERENCES recettes (id) ON DELETE CASCADE');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE recettes_ingredients ADD CONSTRAINT FK_33E6DB8E3EC4DCE FOREIGN KEY (ingredients_id) REFERENCES ingredients (id) ON DELETE CASCADE');
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE boulangerie');
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE recettesPerso');
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE rememberme_token');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE ingredientsRecettes CHANGE quantite quantite DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE ingredientsRecettes RENAME INDEX idrecette TO recette_id');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE ingredientsRecettes RENAME INDEX idingredient TO ingredients_id');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE boulangerie (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, recette INT DEFAULT NULL, nom TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, poids DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL, recettePerso INT DEFAULT NULL, INDEX recette_perso (recettePerso), INDEX recette (recette), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB COMMENT = \'\' ');
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE recettesPerso (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, idUtilisateur INT DEFAULT NULL, nom TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, ingredients INT NOT NULL, ingredientsPerso INT NOT NULL, INDEX ingredientsPerso (ingredientsPerso), INDEX idUtilisateur (idUtilisateur, ingredients), INDEX ingredients (ingredients), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB COMMENT = \'\' ');
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE rememberme_token (series CHAR(88) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, value CHAR(88) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, lastUsed DATETIME NOT NULL, class VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, username VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci, UNIQUE INDEX series (series), PRIMARY KEY(series)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB COMMENT = \'\' ');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE boulangerie ADD CONSTRAINT boulangerie_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (recettePerso) REFERENCES recettesperso (id)');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE boulangerie ADD CONSTRAINT boulangerie_ibfk_3 FOREIGN KEY (recette) REFERENCES recettes (id)');
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE recettes_ingredients');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE ingredientsRecettes CHANGE quantite quantite DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT NULL');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE ingredientsRecettes RENAME INDEX recette_id TO idRecette');
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE ingredientsRecettes RENAME INDEX ingredients_id TO idIngredient');
    }
}
```

Comment: have you generate a new migration ? what's the command you try to do the migration ? . from the message error you have  , it told you that the table **ingredientsrecettes** exist already on the database , so you need to remove it from your DBMS manually

Comment: every table already exist, i created my DB with phpmyadmin and mapped it with Doctrine.

Comment: Instead of showing the entities, showing the migration might be more helpful. Also, before changing/creating the entities you might want to do a `bin/console doctrine:migrations:status` to make sure both the DB schema and your entity annotations are in sync. Then change your entities/generate the migration.

Comment: @LouRaki `doctrine:migrations:diff` tries to compare your database schema with the annotations in your entity. Since the tables already exist there might be some problems between your annotation `ingredientsRecettes` and the actual table name `ingredientsrecettes` (notice the r vs R in recettes).

Comment: Ok I renamed the JoinTable "recettes_ingredients" and the migration worked. Thank you !

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should not manually modify, delete or create tables or fields in the database. All changes should be documented by migrations, otherwise you might have incompatibilities and might encounter errors in different environments.